# What is the correct return type of strpos? Searching for the '@' char

Tags: php

For example I have a string `I am @ the penthouse.`

I need to know how to find the character "@" in php string and the position of the character.

I tried strpos but its not working.

Thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT:

I've been using this for get the character:

```
$text = "I am @ the penthouse";

$pos = strrpos($text, '@');

if($pos == true)
{
    echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: show us the code you tired using `strpos`

Comment: After updating your question, your issue is strpos doesn't return true, it returns the position in a number. You should run if($pos !== false)

Comment: Aiyoh, I feel dumb for this. Thanks for the solutions guys. You are great

Comment: But I'm still wondering what the expression !== false means

Comment: @comebal !== false means it can't equal anything except for the actual false value. For example, false == 0 but false !== 0. Double equal signs are loose comparisons when triple equal signs are strict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this

**Note,** I'm using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), not reverse counterpart, [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
if (($pos = strpos('I am @ the penthouse.', '@') !== false) {
  echo "pos found: {$pos}";
}
else {
  echo "no @ found";
}
```

---

**Note:** Because `@` could be the first character in a string, [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) could return a `0`. Consider the following:

```
// check twitter name for @
if (strpos('@twitter', '@')) { ... }

// resolves to
if (0) {
  // this will never run!
}
```

So, [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will explicitly return `false` when no match is found. This is how to properly check for a substring position:

```
// check twitter name for @
if (strpos('@twitter', '@') !== false) {
  // valid twitter name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function `strpos()` for that purpose. Like `strrpos()` it searches for a substring - or at least a char - in a string but it the returns the **first** position of that substring **or boolean(false)** if the substring was not found. So the snippet would look like:

```
$position = strpos('I am @ the penthouse', '@');
if($position === FALSE) {
    echo 'The @ was not found';
} else {
    echo 'The @ was found at position ' . $position;
}
```

**Note** that there are common pitfalls that come with `strpos()` and `strrpos()` in php.

1 . **Check Type of the return value!**

Imagine the following example :

```
if(!strpos('@stackoverflow', '@')) {
    echo 'the string contains no @';
}
```

The would output that '@' was not found although the string contains an '@'. Thats because of the weak data typing in PHP. The previous strpos() call will return int(0) because it is the first char in string. But unless you enforce a strict type check using the '===' operator this int(0) will be handle as FALSE. This is the correct way:

```
if(strpos('@stackoverflow', '@') === FALSE) {
    echo 'the string contains no @';
}
```

2 . **Use the correct order of arguments!**

The signature of strpos is:

```
strpos($haystack, $needle [, $start]);
```

Thats **unlike** other str* functions in PHP where the $needle is the first arg.

Keep this in mind! ;)

Comment: OP, Keep in mind you should also make sure the $position !== false, which means it wasn't found.

Comment: Hi Guys, Its not working for me. The character is not being read. But when I tried like other letters, it is working

Comment: @comebal - What PHP Version? echo phpinfo(); if you don't know.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I thought yours should have been accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me in PHP 5.4.7:

`$pos = strpos('I am @ the penthouse', '@');`

What do you mean exactly by `strpos` is not working?

Comment: Hi Guys, Its not working for me. The character is not being read. But when I tried like other letters, it is working

Answer (score -1):

Look this is working for me, it will also work for you

```
$string = "hello i am @ your home";
 echo strpos($string,"@");
```

Answer (score -2):

i hope this will help -

```
<?php
$string = "I am @ the penthouse";
$desired_char = "@";

// checking whether @ present or not
if(strstr($string, $desired_char)){

   // the position of the character
   $position = strpos('I am @ the penthouse', $desired_char);
   echo $position;
}
else echo $desired_char." Not found!";
?>
```

Comment: Don't scan the string twice